# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" during jquery request to infusionsoft server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A client who uses infusionsoft has specified a form she wants to use. The only catch is that I am suppose to put the form in a popup and not redirect to infusionsoft's "hey thanks" page after submission. The popup should simply be closed after submission, and then continue on with the app.

To do this, I have tried to use some jquery, but I am a novice, so I don't really know what is going on.

The error I get in Chrome's web tools console is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <".
When I click on the source file to the right of the "unexpected token <" error (which says it is on line 123), I see on line 123 the beginning of a doctype declaration. There is nothing before line 123.

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"`  `"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Here is the Form html:

```
<div data-role="modalview" id="registerForm" style="width: 90%">
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://xt156.infusionsoft.com/app/form/process/515000abb7aedb966f8cbcf5743ba6b7" class="infusion-form" method="POST" id="infosoftForm">
        <input name="inf_form_xid" type="hidden" value="515000abb7aedb966f8cbcf5743ba6b7" />
        <input name="inf_form_name" type="hidden" value="RADIO BUTTON &#a;WEBFORM" />
        <input name="infusionsoft_version" type="hidden" value="1.31.0.38" />
        <div class="infusion-field">
            <label for="inf_field_FirstName">First Name *</label>
            <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="inf_field_FirstName" name="inf_field_FirstName" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="infusion-field">
            <label for="inf_field_LastName">Last Name *</label>
            <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="inf_field_LastName" name="inf_field_LastName" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="infusion-field">
            <label for="inf_field_Email">Email *</label>
            <input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="inf_field_Email" name="inf_field_Email" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="infusion-field">
            <label for="inf_custom_MyCategory">Who Am I... *</label>
            <select id="inf_custom_MyCategory" name="inf_custom_MyCategory">
                <option value="">Please select one</option>
                <option value="Single or Couple">Single or Couple</option>
                <option value="Coach">Coach</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="infusion-submit">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="infusionsoftSubmit" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

And here is the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $form = $('#infosoftForm');
$form.submit(function () {
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function () {
        closeRegisterFormWindow();
    }, 'jsonp');
    return false;
});
});
```

Again, I am a novice and don't really understand all the moving parts. What is happening, and what do I need to do to fix it?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Try running jquery from a CDN - add this to your page head: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`.  It looks like you're trying to load something that isn't jquery.

Comment: Huh. I added that script to the page head and got some unexpected behavior. The popup window doesn't even fire now. Going to have to look into that for a bit